# nginx wildcard subdomain to sub directory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

i have currenty a nginx config that's work fine with 1 level subdomains. But i want to support all level subdomains (second, third).

**My currently config is:**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name "~^(?<sub>.+)\.domain\.com$";
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log_$sub.atam.de.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error_log_$sub.atam.de.log;

    set $root /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/$sub/www/;
    root $root;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    ...
}
```

Can i splitted the $sub variable by every point (.) and add the following to $root for every splitted /subdomains/$splittedSub/.

**I wan't:**
a.domain.com -> /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/a/www/
b.a.domain.com -> /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/a/subdomains/b/www/

Comment: You could use three `server` blocks, one for each nesting level. Then `include` all of the common configuration from a separate file.

Comment: Is that not possible to make as rescursive, because i could be more then 3 levels..?

Comment: Or can duplicate the $sub variable (example: $sub2) and replace all the dots (.) to /subdomains/? Example a.b.domain.com will replaced to /subdomains/a/subdomains/b/. So i can use $sub2 in $root between /var/www/domain.com/$sub2/www/ -> /var/www/domain.com//subdomains/a/subdomains/b/www/

Comment: This works https://serverfault.com/a/250219/454869